# How to read text from a webpage using Java?

Tags: java

**Edit** - *I realize similar questions have been asked before, but I found previous answers (including the one marked as duplicate) insufficient. As already stated by the body of the question. Specifically, I wanted either 1) a non-jsoup solution or 2) some help on how to implement jsoup.*

I'm learning Java, and have been trying for the last couple of hours to figure out how to read displayed text from a website. I've found a lot of solutions and run into road blocks with all of them.

**IOUtils** - I don't know if this was removed or I'm just doing it wrong, but my import statements aren't working. Both of the following return "package does not exist" errors.

```
import org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils;
import org.apache.commons.compress.utils.IOUtils;
```

**jsoup** - no idea how to use it or import it. Definitely a potential area of learning for me, but I'd prefer to use a standard java solution. If this is the direction I have to go, though, I'll figure it out I guess.

**This code** actually functions, at least, but it returns the html rather than just the displayed text. I'm trying to read [this page](http://www.uniprot.org/uniprot/B5ZC00.fasta), which displays extremely simple text but has such complex code I don't know how to parse it from that source. Unless I already know what I'm looking for, which defeats the purpose.

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;

public class ReadTextFromURL {

   public static void main(String[] args) {

      try {

         URL url = new URL("http://www.uniprot.org/uniprot/B5ZC00");

        // read text returned by server
         BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(url.openStream()));

         String line;
         while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println(line);
         }
         in.close();

      }
      catch (MalformedURLException e) {
         System.out.println("Malformed URL: " + e.getMessage());
      }
      catch (IOException e) {
         System.out.println("I/O Error: " + e.getMessage());
      }
   }
}
```

Any help on where to look for an effective and versatile solution to read text off a web page would be very appreciated!

Comment: Learn and use a Java HTML parser such as JSoup. Avoid re-inventing the wheel, but rather use tried and trusted tools that have been built specifically to solve this problem.

Comment: `"1) a non-jsoup solution"` -- Don't re-invent the wheel. `"or 2) some help on how to implement jsoup."` -- What you need is something far more basic, how to use classpath to allow you to use jar files with your program. Or if using an IDE, how to include a jar on your build path.

Comment: Yup. Hence not wanting to learn all that for one file. Oh well, guess I have to. Thank you for your help.

Comment: For one file or 50 files, it's a heck of a lot easier and safer to parse the file with a parser than to try to kludge your own. I can't tell you how often we see folks here trying to solve this with regex which can lead to serious problems.